# Please convert my pseudo code to a working Python program

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been looking at the problem given below

> Given a set S = {x1, x2, . . . , xn} of integers, and an integer t (called target) decide if there is a subset of S whose sum is equal to t.

Will anyone, please, convert my pseudo code to a working Python program?

```
If L is a set of integers and x is another integer, then we use the shorthand L + x to denote the list of integers derived from L by increasing each element of L by x, i.e. L + x = {`k + x | `k ∈ L}. For example, if L = {1, 5, 9}, then L + 3 = {4, 8, 12}.
```

Below is pseudocode for SSP that is based on the dynamic programming approach

```
1:    L ← {0}
2:    for x ∈ {x1, . . . , xn} do
3:        L ← L ∪ (L + x)
4:        remove from L every element that is greater than t
5:     end for
6:     return True if t ∈ L, False otherwise
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.
StackOverflow is not a coding or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, no, we cannot turn this into working Python code for you.  That's cheating.

Algebraically, the result is much easier.  The target can be achieved *iff*

1. target is divisible by x; **and**
2. target <= sum(S)

sum(S) = x * (n+1)*n/2

Your code actually constructs a solution; this is not necessary.